# reuse intent service code in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

In my Android App, I use an intent service to retrieve important data for my app and store them in my SQL DB. I regularly launch this service with alarm manager.

When the app is launched by the user, the activity check in DB if the needed data are there.

- if yes, the standard UI is shown
- if no, I have to make the user wait and launch the data download

My question is : how could I reuse the most code I wrote in the intent service when the DL is launched from the activity, using an asynctask ?

Would you mind sharing with me your best practices and advices?

A big thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According To My understanding from your question.
you should call intent service from activity and use broadcast receiver for any change occur in database. and update your ui. means first start your

1) intent service to call your web service after getting callback
2) insert into database.
3) apply [contentobserver](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/) to observe any changes in database (by observing specific URI)
4) and update your ui according to changes in database

Comment: Hi mcd, I agree with your solution. But, IMHO, using an intent service and broadcast receiver to communicate with the UI is not very convenient. Asynctask has been designed for that and does the job quite well. That's why I would like to use an AsyncTask when the HTTP work is requested by the UI, and an intent service when it is alarm scheduled. Reusing the same code if possible!

Comment: Are you sure asynctask is good for and designed for it? and i think asynctask is not good for long running task (like network operation).

Comment: OKay! Let's try and implement your solution. Thanks for your help. With your solution, I still have an issue : how could my UI could get informed if my network task fails?

Comment: You can use local broadcast manager and sharedprefrence to manage httprequest status . create constants for server response for ok,network error,server error.and notify your ui accordingly if user is foreground local broadcast will help you and if user is on background and comes again sharedprefrence value will solve your problem.

Comment: In my current project I am using volley library and its response are inserted in db using intent service .

Comment: okay cool, I'll try. I accept your answer! thanks for your help!